# 3rd party library catches my exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, event-handling

I've got a 3rd party API library which contains a set of request functions. Responses are got by subscribing to events.

If and exception is thrown in my event handler - the 3rd party library catches it and does nothing after. This doesn't let me know if I have any problems with my code.

Is there any way to catch my exceptions before the 3rd party library does?

I thought on writing wrappers for event handlers but it doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Subscribing to `AppDomain.FirstChanceException` doesn't give any effect.

Comment: Can you take your event handler, wrap it in a try ... catch and pass the whole thing into the 3rd party lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to catch my exceptions before the 3rd party library does?

```
HandlerFunction()
{
    try
    {
        /* place handler body here */
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        /* you may store/log the exception object here */
    }
}
ThirdPartyObject.Event += HandlerFunction;
```

In the catch clause, you may also add your exception object to a global error log so that you can keep track of it.

Also you may place a breakpoint in the exception clause to debug your errors.